# simple UPDATE query in MySQL take a long time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with simple update query what always appearing in my mysql-slow-query.log table is not big and contain just only `3021 rows`.

the query looks like :

```
UPDATE 'address' 
SET 'user' = 1013 
WHERE 'id_adress' = '1' 
    AND 'date' = '2012-06-04'
```

> Query_time: 2.664413  Lock_time: 0.000043  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1

when I examinate this query with:

```
select  'user' = 1013 
from 'address' 
where  'id_adress' = '1' 
   AND 'date' = '2012-06-04'
```

then looks very fast `1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

Why this simple update query take such a lot of time?
How to fix it?

Comment: Have you any indexes set up on the table? Indexes may affect update performance speed on queries negatively even though they speed up `SELECT` queries.

Comment: @Ren there is no indexes on this table, only 1 primary key on ID .

Comment: Since these queries make little sense due to having single-quoted everything I assume you are actually generating them with some client language and this is the SQL code the *think* it's actually running. My advice is to double check: 1) What the generated SQL code is 2) How that SQL performs when ran outside (v.g. from your favourite MySQL client).

Comment: do you using any trigger on this table?

Comment: I've executed code in phpmyadmin and I see that works fast `0,02s` , maybe some cashe ? , by the way no trigger in use

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or InnoDB? What are the results of "explain select  'user' = 1013 from 'address' where  'id_adress' = '1' AND 'date' = '2012-06-04'"? What are the results of "show full processlist" while the update query is running?

Answer (score 1):

first check if your table is not crashed, 
if it is then repair your the table.

second try to index those two fields used in where clause